# stop animation doesn't work with image view

Tags: image, animation, swift, view, freeze

I'm trying to stop an animation, a rectangle (created by code) and it works with this code, but when use the same `removeAllAnimation` with an `imageView` (replacing the rectangle created by code) it doesn't work...

----correction---

### it work wrong, stop the animation but the image view goes in the position where i've put it in the storyboard and not where is when i tap the stop button...

```
@IBAction func ButtonStop(sender: UIButton) {
        var layer = movementBar.layer.presentationLayer() as CALayer
        var frame = layer.frame

        movementBar.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        movementBar.frame = frame
}
```

`movementBar` is an `imageView` filled with color, whit soft edge, before i've created by code a rectangle with cgrect (x, y, w, h)
thanks for help!

here the code to make animation, there are 2 func that make movement to down and after to up, pressing a button the movementBar stop and i read position:

```
func movementUp() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.speed, animations: {
          self.movementBar.frame = CGRect (x:0, y:self.yUp, width:self.barWidth, height:self.barHeight)
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            if animationFinished {
                self.movementDown()
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I had done same thing** please check demo project
[Download from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/80cmaz1updk2w4v/demoAnimation%202.zip?dl=0)
Please let me know what's the different between your implementation and mine.

Comment: really i don't know why whit your project works, with my no... i try to rewrite the code from start, maybe something went wrong from start... thanks for help!

Comment: WC :) and best of luck, i tried in both objective-c and swift both working... and added constraint too in UIImageView to create problem but it working fine.